# Run an SSH command to stream Rails logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ssh, tail

I would like to create a function that is able to run a remote script via SSH that streams Rails logs. Currently, I have to do this manually:

```
ssh dev_server
cd /var/log/.../rails_app
tail -f production.log web.log
```

I would like to run a command like `rails_logs`, run the above commands and stream my logs. How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to consider installing https://airbrake.io/ instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just running the command you want in your initial ssh connection?

```
ssh dev_server 'tail -F /var/log/.../rails_app/log/*log'
```

- Using `-F` instead of `-f` will follow a filename rather than an inode. Handy if your logs ever rotate

If you want to make this easier, you could put your tail command into a remote script which you could call:

```
ssh dev_server my_tail_script
```

You could also alias this locally and just call your alias:

```
# put this line into your `.bashrc` or `.profile`:
alias tl='ssh dev_server my_tail_script'

# Now you can just call your alias:
tl
```

Comment: I wouldn't create a separate script just for this, I prefer the inline command. But I get this error when I try to run it: `zsh: no matches found: /var/log/rails_app/*log`. The path to the logs is correct.

Comment: Try it fully qualified. It might be interpolating the filename locally before sending the command.

Comment: Indeed, it worked. Thank you. So it isn't possible to use globbing there? How can I force it interpolate the filename remotely and not locally?

Comment: You could try wrapping the globbed command in quotes and try that? Otherwise you're down to creating a remote script, or naming all of the files you want to tail individually

Comment: `ssh dev_server 'tail -F /var/log/.../rails_app/log/*log'` will expand the wildcard on the remote system. Personally, I might do `ssh dev_server 'cd /var/log/.../rails_app && tail -F *log'` instead.

Comment: Answer updated to include the quotes around the globbed command